# Why didn't the minimum_should_match parameter remove these spurious results?

Tags: elasticsearch

This [tutorial(Ngrams for Compound Words)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/ngrams-compound-words.html#ngrams-compound-words) says judicious use of the minimum_should_match parameter can remove these spurious results.
I followed this tutorial step by step. I got the same results on each step except the last one.

In my case, the minimum_should_match parameter can't remove these spurious results.

Test:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search?pretty -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "text": {
                "query":                "Gesundheit",
                "minimum_should_match": "80%"
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Response:

```
{

    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 3,
        "max_score": 5.215484,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "my_type",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 5.215484,
                "_source": {
                    "text": "Weltgesundheitsorganisation"
                }
            }
            ,
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "my_type",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.28685358,
                "_source": {
                    "text": "Militargeschichte"
                }
            }
            ,
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "my_type",
                "_id": "5",
                "_score": 0.28685358,
                "_source": {
                    "text": "Rindfleischetikettierungsuberwachungsaufgabenubertragungsgesetz"
                }
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

Why didn't the minimum_should_match parameter remove these spurious results in my case? Not sure where I am probably wrong.

Note: Running this on Elasticsearch 2.4.4 and 5.0.1.

**EDIT:**
Explanation of the query:

```
{
    "valid": true,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "explanations": [
        {
            "index": "my_index",
            "valid": true,
            "explanation": "+(text:ges text:esu text:sun text:und text:ndh text:dhe text:hei text:eit) #ConstantScore(+ConstantScore(_type:my_type))"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "took": 20,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 3,
        "max_score": 5.7275248,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_shard": 0,
                "_node": "_cVmNZULS3C-yMl4o6FobA",
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "my_type",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 5.7275248,
                "_source": {
                    "text": "Weltgesundheitsorganisation"
                },
                "_explanation": {
                    "value": 5.7275243,
                    "description": "sum of:",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "value": 5.7275243,
                            "description": "sum of:",
                            "details": [
                                {
                                    "value": 0.34488404,
                                    "description": "weight(text:ges in 3) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                                    "details": ...
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    "value": 0.7689487,
                                    "description": "weight(text:esu in 3) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                                    "details": ...
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    "value": 0.7689487,
                                    "description": "weight(text:sun in 3) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                                    "details": ...
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    "value": 0.7689487,
                                    "description": "weight(text:und in 3) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                                    "details": ...
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    "value": 0.7689487,
                                    "description": "weight(text:ndh in 3) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                                    "details": ...
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    "value": 0.7689487,
                                    "description": "weight(text:dhe in 3) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                                    "details": ...
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    "value": 0.7689487,
                                    "description": "weight(text:hei in 3) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                                    "details": ...
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    "value": 0.7689487,
                                    "description": "weight(text:eit in 3) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                                    "details": ...
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                        ,
                        {
                            "value": 0,
                            "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
                            "details": ...
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
            ,
            {
                "_shard": 0,
                "_node": "_cVmNZULS3C-yMl4o6FobA",
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "my_type",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.34488404,
                "_source": {
                    "text": "Militargeschichte"
                },
                "_explanation": {
                    "value": 0.34488404,
                    "description": "sum of:",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "value": 0.34488404,
                            "description": "sum of:",
                            "details": [
                                {
                                    "value": 0.34488404,
                                    "description": "weight(text:ges in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                                    "details": ...
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                        ,
                        {
                            "value": 0,
                            "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
                            "details": ...
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
            ,
            {
                "_shard": 0,
                "_node": "_cVmNZULS3C-yMl4o6FobA",
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "my_type",
                "_id": "5",
                "_score": 0.34488404,
                "_source": {
                    "text": "Rindfleischetikettierungsuberwachungsaufgabenubertragungsgesetz"
                },
                "_explanation": {
                    "value": 0.34488404,
                    "description": "sum of:",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "value": 0.34488404,
                            "description": "sum of:",
                            "details": [
                                {
                                    "value": 0.34488404,
                                    "description": "weight(text:ges in 4) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                                    "details": ...
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                        ,
                        {
                            "value": 0,
                            "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
                            "details": ...
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Index settings:

```
{
    "my_index": {
        "aliases": { },
        "mappings": {
            "my_type": {
                "properties": {
                    "text": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "trigrams"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1486975897911",
                "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "trigrams_filter": {
                            "type": "ngram",
                            "min_gram": "3",
                            "max_gram": "3"
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                        "trigrams": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase"
                                ,
                                "trigrams_filter"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "d-UluLwqSiOQjmYTwJze8w",
                "version": {
                    "created": "2040199"
                }
            }
        },
        "warmers": { }
    }
}
```

**My Application of Elasticsearch** is at <s>http://35.184.69.214/elasticsearch-head/</s>
<s>User: user</s>
<s>Password: elasticsearch</s>

Comment: Have you tried to "explain"  the query and see what it returns?

Comment: I appended the explanation of the query. I think there's nothing wrong about the query.